# select 2nd row in Plsql

Tags: oracle, select, plsql, top-n

Lets say I have the following table:

```
 SomeTable(
    id, 
    price
 )
```

How do I select the 2nd highest priced row from this table?
Note : This has to be done in Pl/SQL, in a database agnostic way.
Is it possible to do this without any loops?

1. I know how this is done using Oracle constructs like `rownum` or mysql constructs like `limit`, so I am not looking for those.

Comment: What exactly `This has to be done in Pl/SQL` means to you?

Comment: how do you expect a solution based on an oracle proprietary pl/sql to be database-agnostic?

Comment: I didnt mean Oracle proprietary pl-sql. I meant a code block - which would probably run anywhere - lets say Java for the sake of commenting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't this simple? God knows why I didn't think about it before!

select max(price) from tnum
 where price <> (select max(price) from tnum)

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY, price NUMBER NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (1, 10);
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (2, 20);
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (3, 20);
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (4, 30);

SELECT id, price 
 FROM (
       SELECT id, price, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY price DESC) AS r
         FROM mytable
      )
 WHERE r=2;

 ID PRICE
--- -----
  2    20
  3    20
```

Comment: I thought RANK() was an analytic function used in Oracle.I wanted a code block,preferably.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. In that case, I'd go for `SELECT * FROM SomeTable ORDER BY price DESC`, discard the first row and fetch another one. That should be as database agnostic as it gets...