# Oracle query to find the 2nd highest

Tags: sql, oracle, top-n

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [select 2nd row in Plsql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13700106/select-2nd-row-in-plsql)

I have this database 
movies (id: int, name: string, years: int, rating: ﬂoat)

movies_genres (movie_id: int, genre: string)

I need to find the 
For each genre, ﬁnd the 2nd best rated movie. Can this be generalized to
ﬁnd the i’th rated movie?

Answer (score 3):

Look into using `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT rating maxrating, genre
FROM (
  SELECT
    rating, 
    genre, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY genre ORDER BY rating DESC) rn
 FROM movies_genres mg
   JOIN movies m1 ON mg.movie_id=m1.movie_id 
 GROUP BY rating,genre
) t 
WHERE rn = 2
```

And here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/32d0e/4).

--EDIT

I added `GROUP BY rating,genre` to remove potential duplicates.  As @JW correctly points out, you could also replace `ROW_NUMBER` with `DENSE_RANK` which would handle the groupings for you.

Good luck.

Comment: I rather use [DENSE_RANK](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/rank-dense-rank-first-last-analytic-functions.php#dense_rank) as it determines duplicates `:D`

Comment: @JW. -- Great comment if OP wanted to include the Movie Name.  However since OP just wants Genre/Highest Ranking, I think ROW_NUMBER() works just as well :)  Good point though.

Comment: but how will you handle these records? `rating, genre`, `10, 1`, `11, 2`, `11,3`, `12,4`. how will you get the second highest rating? will you only return one record?

Comment: Great question, see edit.  I assume you were referring to duplicated ratings.  Thanks :)